# Difference between sudo nautilus and sudo -E nautilus

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, nautilus

There was latest installed ubuntu 17.04 and I was unable to run command sudo nautilus it was giving error. Then I searched on google and tried sudo -E nautilus and it worked. What is the difference between both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`sudo` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sudo/sudo.8) describes `-E` thus:

> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Typically, `sudo` cleans up the environment it provides to the command it runs; `-E` disables that (if the user is allowed to). You can see the difference by comparing the outputs of `sudo env` and `sudo -E env`.

Nautilus needs a number of environment variables to find information it needs, or access other processes it needs to communicate with; the default clean-up prevents this from working.